# Search an entire database table with multiple fields using php

Tags: php, mysql

I have a mysql database table with about 15 fields. I want to search the entire field for the string input by the user.. I dont want to use "or" in my query for joining multiple fields as it will slow down the processing. Can anyone please help me with alternate method?

Comment: you use this php class : http://code.google.com/p/anywhereindb/

Answer (score 4):

You can create a [`FULLTEXT` index](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html) on any number of fields. Performance should be ok (much better than `LIKE`).

Example:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name ADD FULLTEXT ft_index_name (col1, col2, col3);
```

Then to query:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE MATCH(col1, col2, col3) AGAINST ('search_term')
```

If you need extra performance, look into [Sphinx](http://sphinxsearch.com/) for example, which functions as a drop-in replacement for the native MySQL `FULLTEXT`.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to use OR then better is to use `concat` to concat all 15 fields and then search for needle with `like`. Something like this:

```
select * from MyTable
where concat(col1,col2,col3,col4,col5,col6,col7,col8,col9,col11,col11,col12,col13,col14,col15)
like '%myval%';
```

However I'm not sure performance wise this will be any better than using OR.